# Change specific menu item text size in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change a specific menu item **text size** in Navigation Drawer. I want the first item **text size** to be different from the athoer.

Any idea how to implement this?

Here is my activity_main_drawer file:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_first"
        android:title="First" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_second"
        android:title="Second" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_third"
        android:title="Third" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 1):

try textAppearance

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:background="your color"
    app:itemTextColor="your color"
    app:itemIconTint="your color"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_first"
    android:title="First" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_second"
    android:title="Second" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_third"
    android:title="Third" />
```

```
    android:title="" />
```

> Try this code :)